# Right way to return the UISlider method's INT?

Tags: ios, logic

I am working on a game. I have a bunch of bad guy planes attacking good guy planes. Now I want the user to be able to manually select how many missiles to shoot at the bad guy planes.

I have a method which adds a subview containing a UISlider to select how many missiles to shoot.

Example (flow of code):

1) Bad guys, good guys planes see each other.

2) Jump to UISlider method.

3) (>need int to continue program here<)

4) User selects number in UISlider method and selector is called.

5) UISlider selector - (how do I get back to location 3?)

My problem is not the programming but rather the logic. To be specific, what is the right way to return the UISlider method's INT back to the code location which originally called the UISlider method?

Also it would be great to be able to reuse the same method (the game has a lot of bad guys).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a good way to return a UISlider value.

First as Abdullah Shafique stated, you need to create method for UISLider programmatically like:

```
[yourSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Then you might have to call the method you want after selecting the number like:

```
- (void)valueChanged:(id)sender {
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
    int value = slider.value;

    [self shootMissles:value]; //This line will send the value of slider to the method below.
}
```

I'm not familiar with INPUT and APPLE BASIC but the line [self shootMissles:value] will pass the slider value to a method where you can do whatever you wish with it. For example:

```
 - (void)shootMissles:(float)numOfMissles {
     //code to shoot x number of missles based on UISlider value - be mindful 
     //that UISlider spits out float values, you will have to round to get whole numbers.
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Again, I am creating everything programmatically. No IBAction. What I am looking for is something similar to the INPUT feature in APPLE BASIC.

Comment: @sangony any luck in implementing this?

Comment: Sorry for delay. It appears that there is no good way to do what I was trying to do. At least not that I have come across so far but I will give your answer thumbs up nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

IBAction the UISlider:

```
- (IBAction)valueChanged:(id)sender {
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
    int value = slider.value;
}
```

**EDIT**: Add IBAction:

```
[yourSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Comment: I am creating the subview, UISlider programmatically.

Comment: Thanks Abdullah but I got all that. My problem is not the programming but the logic. How do I return the selected value back to the point in the code from which the UISlider method was called?